# R- Remove all numeric character from right until non numeric character is reached

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I am attempting to clean out addresses that come in this format `1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS 670378863` or `55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC 27529`
As shown, the postal codes towards the end of the address are inconsistent and I would like to remove the numeric portion of the address from the right overall. In excel I am able to use the `=LEFT(A2, Len(A2)-x))` but it's still not good, since the x is not variable based on the length of the numeric characters in the string.

How can I use R or regex, to remove all numeric characters from the right until a non-numeric character is reached?

Expected output to look like -

| raw_Address | clean_Address |
| --- | --- |
| 1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS 670378863 | 1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS |
| 55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC 27529 | 55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC |

Answer (score 1):

We may use `trimws` from `base R` - match the one or more whitespace followed by the one or more digits which remove the one at the right

```
df1$clean_Address <- trimws(df1$raw_Address, whitespace = "\\s+\\d+")
```

-output

```
> df1
                         raw_Address            clean_Address
1 1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS 670378863 1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS
2       55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC 27529   55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(raw_Address = c("1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS 670378863", 
"55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC 27529")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using {stringr}

```r
raw_Address <-  c("1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS 670378863", "55 Cabela Dr 
GARNER NC 27529")

library(stringr)

str_replace(raw_Address, "\\s\\d+$", "")

#or even more simply

str_remove(raw_Address, "\\s\\d+$")

#> [1] "1804 E Osage Rd DERBY KS" "55 Cabela Dr GARNER NC"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>